# Using Smart TV bluetooth remote control to control a PC

Tags: windows, bluetooth, remote-control

Is there any way to use a Smart TV Bluetooth remote control to control a PC?
Actually, I have paired the remote with the PC and I see a device named "smart remotes" in the device manager. But it does not work.

Update:
The model of the remote control is **Remote Control Smart Touch** [RMCTPF](http://www.uk-topstore.co.uk/samsung-aa59-00759a-remote-control-smart-touch-tm1390-rmctpf-rmctpf1ap1-f-series/). You can see it in the following image.

[image]

Comment: You'll typically need some piece of software that will act as a middleman to make it work...I'll try to find something..

Comment: You'll really need to be more specific to get a solution, which will most likely make the question "off-topic" unfortunately. What TV remote and OS are you on?

Comment: @Raystafarian I updated the question.

Comment: How do you want to "control" the PC? Are you using it for controlling a media player...?

Comment: @K.A Yes, also it has a touchpad, that can be used in the same way that we use laptop touchpad.

Comment: Ever found a solution? It would still be very handy

Comment: @Srneczek I haven't found and don't have access to the remote anymore.